# Webclient sending request body with get request

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I have a spring-boot project called carrental-crud with an h2 memory database, and I want to access one of the endpoints from another project called carrental-api.

I use webClientBuilder for this on my other endpoints, but it is throwing status 500 with bad request when I try using it in postman.

I use JPArepository to access the h2 db with a query, this is how my orderRepository looks :

```
@Transactional
@Query(nativeQuery = true,value = "select count(*) from TBL_ORDER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=?1")
public int getTotalOrders(long customerId);
```

Then in my adminCustomerService class, I use it like this  :

```
public int getTotalOrders(long customerId) {
    loggerService.writeLoggerMsg("LISTED TOTAL ORDERS FOR A CUSTOMER");
    
    return orderRepository.getTotalOrders(customerId);
}
```

And then in my adminCustomerController :

```
@GetMapping(path = "/totalorders")
public int getTotalOrders(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
    return adminCustomerService.getTotalOrders(customer.getCustomerId());
}
```

and in my postman request body, I write :

```json
{
  "customerId": 2
}
```

This works in my carrental-crud, but how can I recreate this in my carrental-api?

And using the same request body in postman, but I keep getting the error status 500 with bad request

EDIT :
I managed to get this to work by using parameters instead of a request body.

This is how my adminCustomerService looks :

```
public int getTotalOrders(long customerId) {
   int orders = webClientBuilder.build()
            .get()
            .uri("http://localhost:8081/crud/v1/totalorders/" + customerId)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Integer>() {})
            .log()
            .block();
    return orders;
}
```

And my adminCustomerController :

```
@GetMapping(path = "/totalorders/{customerId}")
public int getTotalOrders(@PathVariable long customerId) {

    return adminCustomerService.getTotalOrders(customerId);
}
```

Comment: 500 HTTP status code does not represent a bad request. Can you post the stack trace of both the caller and the target services? Thanks.

Comment: I edited the post with the stack trace

Comment: You should also get a proper stack trace on the crud service side?

Comment: I understand, how should I get that stack trace if it only returns 200 ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are simply sending `customerId` as a `Long` in your programmatic call when you should be sending something like the JSON that you showed. The simplest way to solve this is by creating a class that matches such JSON structure:

```java
public class CustomerRequest {
    private long customerId;

    public CustomerRequest(long customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public long getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }
}
```

And then you need to create an instance of such class when calling the API as follows:

```java
public Flux<Integer> getTotalOrders(long customerId) {
    loggerService.writeLoggerMsg("LISTED TOTAL ORDERS FOR A CUSTOMER");

    return ((RequestBodySpec) webClientBuilder
            .build()
            .get()
            .uri("localhost:8081/crud/v1/totalorders"))
            .body(Flux.just(new CustomerRequest(customerId)), CustomerRequest.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(Integer.class);
}
```

---

Still, I would suggest you having a more RESTful approach in your endpoint and use path parameter instead of a request body in a GET request. Something along the following lines:

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/customers/{customerId}/total-orders")
public int getTotalOrders(@PathVariable long customerId) {
    return adminCustomerService.getTotalOrders(customerId);
}
```

Then you would make a request to this endpoint as follows:

```java
public Flux<Integer> getTotalOrders(long customerId) {
    loggerService.writeLoggerMsg("LISTED TOTAL ORDERS FOR A CUSTOMER");

    return webClientBuilder
            .build()
            .get()
            .uri("localhost:8081/crud/v1/customers/{customerId}/total-orders", customerId))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(Integer.class);
}
```

I would suggest you read the following online resources:

- https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-pathvariable

Comment: I already have a Customer Entity , that looks similiar to your CustomerRequest example. 

I will try to use that instead of CustomerRequest like in your example, thanks

Comment: sadly , it didn't work, I have edited the post with my new getTotalOrders method and my new stack trace error

Comment: The error is exactly the same, which makes no sense. What is the URL that you are using for the Postman call? Nevertheless, you shouldn't be using a body in a GET request. I would suggest you use a path variable or a query parameter instead. If you are open for it I can suggest how your code in the controller side should look like.

Comment: Absolutely, I would be very thankful if you could show me

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please check it ;)

Comment: I managed to get it working with parameters as well, I will edit my post and accept your answer, thanks!